# Unable to delete image from the drive in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, blogs

I am unable to delete the file (uploaded by the user) on calling the destroy method in the post controller.

I am able to upload the file to my drive that is 
root/public/uploads/attachment

this is my filesystem

```
'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('uploads'),
    ],
```

This is what i have tried in my controller

```
 public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post=Post::find($post->id);
    Storage::disk('uploads')->delete($post->image);
    $post->categories()->detach();
    $post->tags()->detach();
    $post->delete();
    return redirect('admin/post')->with('message','Deleted Sucessfully');
}
```

I also have tried

```
unlink(public_path().'/uploads/'.$post->image);
```

But both actions gives the same results the post gets deleted but when i physically check the attachments folder the image is still present there

Comment: What is `$post->image`? Dump it.

Comment: $post->image containes the path to the image. I'm basically saving the address of the image in this column       this is what i get on dum "attachments/15668943372.JPG"

Comment: What does `file _exists(public_path().'/uploads/'.$post->image)` outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the Disk Then try it(Full Path of Image)..

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->delete(public_path().'/uploads/'.$post->image);
```

Or

```
Storage::delete($post->image);
```

And Must use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the full path to the file in order to delete it.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#deleting-files

Try using the full path in `Storage::disk('uploads')->delete($post->image);`